# Putting data from a variable into an array

Tags: c, arrays, variables

Hello good people of Stack Overflow. Need some help with my code. I am basically trying to put the data that is stored in the variables itemCode, itemName, pricepu, and stock into array and I have NO IDEA how to do so..

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define totalitems 20
#define maxitems 300

void mainmenu(void);
void alt_menu(void);
void purchase(void);
void edit_item(void);
void update_item(void);
void del_item(void);
void shw_item(void);
void invent_menu(void);
void alt_invent_menu(void);
void daily_trans(void);
void exit_escape(void);
void back_inventmenu(void);
void back_menu(void);
void gst_array(void);


char invent_back, back;                         //global declarations
char input, newinput;
char *barcode;
char taxitems[20][20];
char ntaxitems[20][20];


char line[2048];
char *itemCode[20][20];
char itemName[20][20];
unsigned char pricepu[10][20];
char stock[10][20];

int i, ret, quantpurchase;
double total;

void purchase() {
    char exitcode[] = "-1";
    barcode = (char*) malloc(5);

    printf(" Please key in the barcode number of the product: ");
    scanf(" %s", barcode);


    while(strcmp(exitcode, barcode) != '\0') {

        double priceint;
        FILE *gst = fopen("gst.txt", "r");
        FILE *ngst = fopen("ngst.txt", "r");

        printf("\n");
        printf("\n Item Code Entered: %s\n", barcode);
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), gst) != NULL) { //while fgets does not fail to scan a line
            if(sscanf(line, "%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;]", itemCode, itemName, pricepu, stock) != 4) { 
                //If sscanf failed to scan everything from the scanned line
                //%[^;] scans everything until a ';'
                printf("Bad line detected\n");
                exit(-1);                          //Exit the program
            }

            for (i=0; i < totalitems; i++) {
                if (strcmp(itemCode[i], barcode) == '\0') {
                    printf("\n");
                    printf(" Item Found.\n");
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("===========================================================================\n");
                    printf(" Item code\t Item name \t\t\tPrice\t    Stock Available \n");
                    printf("===========================================================================\n");
                    printf(" %-10s\t %-16s\t\t%s\t    %s\n", itemCode, itemName, pricepu, stock);
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("\n");

                    priceint = strtod(pricepu, (char **)NULL);

                    printf(" How many would you like: ");
                    scanf("%d", &quantpurchase);

                    total = priceint * quantpurchase;
                    printf(" %.2lf\n", total);

                    for (i=0; i<maxitems; i++) {
                        taxitems[0][i] = itemCode[i];
                        printf(" %s", taxitems[0][0]); //HERE'S WHERE I NEED HELP
                    }
                    purchase();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not giving me my desired result. Basically say "AG001" is currently stored under the variable "itemCode", I want to move that into an array. Appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Haha just corrected that mistake. Need to know how to put the data from a variable into an array.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?  Is it not compiling?  Post the compiler error.  Is it crashing?  Is it giving an incorrect result?  What's the expected and the observed behavior?

Comment: Right.. Probably should have placed that in too what's the problem that I am facing.. Umm it's not giving me my desired result. Basically say "AG001" is currently stored under the variable "itemCode", I want to move that into an array.

Comment: Also, you need to post the declaration of "taxitems" array.  It's impossible to deduce what is going wrong just from your "//HERE'S WHERE I NEED HELP" comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
taxitems[0][i] = itemCode[i];
```

You can't copy char arrays with simple assignment.  You need to use the strcpy() function instead.

```
strcpy( taxitems[0][i], itemcode[i], strlen(itemcode[i]);
```

You will need to add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to your code.  You can find the reference to strcpy() function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)